# react-native-snap-carousel takes a lot of time to render photos

Tags: react-native, react-native-snap-carousel

I am using a react-native-snap-carousel to render a photo gallery. I noticed that first entrance to the gallery takes a lot of time to render photos, especially if there are several photos.

```
const renderItem = ( photo) => {     

        console.log(photo);  //<- it shows up quickly in the console, but the photo is not visible for a long time

        return (
            <View style={styles.imgContainer}>
                <Image source={{ uri: photo.item.uri }} style={styles.img} />
            </View>
)};

return (<Carousel
                 ref={carouselRef}
                 data={props.photos}
                 renderItem={renderItem}
                 sliderWidth={sliderWidth}
                 itemWidth={itemWidth}
                 activeSlideAlignment={'center'}
                 onSnapToItem={index => setActiveSlide(index)}
              />)
```

What could be the reason for this behavior?
What can I do with this?